# Why is there so much lava in my underworld when i go into hardmode?

Tags: terraria

So I beat the wall of flesh in expert mode, and I decided i wanted to start farming him. But when I went back to hell, tons of buildings were flooded with lava, and some was on my bridge. When I looked on the map, the lava appeared to be floating. Maybe blocks get removed when corrupted and they let a bunch of lava down? I suspect the save just got corrupted, but if anyone knows why this is happening, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In expert mode, when Hell mobs die, they will leave a block a lava. It's just an expert mode thing. I made holes in my skybridge every other block to let the lava out. Try that if the lava becomes a problem.

Comment: Actually, only [Lava Slimes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lava_Slime) drop lava on death, not any other enemies.

Comment: While it is only lava slimes that drop lava, they're still a pain. I suggest forgoing a walking bridge altogether, and using minecart tracks instead. Lava slimes can't drop lava on your tracks if they can't spawn there at all. Also, minecarts make the later faster stages of WoF a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: I know lava slimes drop lava, but my ENTIRE BRIDGE was either flooded with lava or just barely on top of lava.  Idk, I'm done with the world anyway.